# UIScrollView auto layout not working the width of contentView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

i'm back developing IOS after a year and a half. I'm really having difficulty in make use of UIScrollView and auto layout.

I'm developing an application running just in Iphone and portrait orientation.

I have a simple form inside my content view...

- label
- textField
- textField
- textField
- textField
- button
- textField
- view

  - imageView
  - label

The problem is with the width of the contentView's content. The size is been defined for the labels. I would like (And really have to do) o size it according with the screen size.

Here is my constraints of my first text field:
[image]

Here is my simulator screen running the app:
[image]

how I mentioned before, it seems to get the size according the label and not according the screen size. If I create a constraint of size for the first label, this size change but I would like to get the size dinamically based on screen.

I didn't write any code, I want to do it preferentially using auto layout to understand the concepts of auto layout better.

If someone could help me to solve it... I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pin your `contentView.width` equal to `scrollview.width`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Xcode 10, iOS 12, when you rotate your iPad from landscape to portrait.

Comment: Maybe using a StackView within your ScrollView can also be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783860

Answer (score 0):

Add a constraint to your scroll view's content view child to be the same width as the root-level view.

Comment: Are you saying to make the content view with the same width of view (top level view)? A have already made it! :/

Comment: Exactly. The top-level view will, by definition, always be the width of the device's screen, and that's how wide you want your scrollable content to be.

Comment: I did it... but didn't work. I have my contentView with the same width of view and all itens inside the contentView with constraints of leading and trailing valued in 15.

Comment: Can you paste a snapshot of the content view's constraints?

Comment: Hmm. The equal-widths constraint looks fine. Does InterfaceBuilder show any layout warnings or error?  The only problem I see is that the contentView's height should *not* be set to equal the root view's height, because then it won't scroll.

Comment: The is no error or warning.
Talking about the vertical scrolling I just added a constraint in last element of contentView with botton space with standard value... it worked.

Comment: It possible see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145847/uiscrollview-and-auto-layout-not-working